# What happened to opencpu$browse?

Tags: opencpu

I had an opencpu application packaged in R, and installed locally and used by opencpu$browse(). It's been a while since I used this and after updating opencpu to the latest version, it doesn't recognise this function anymore and I can't find release notes referring to any changes. Has the opencpu design changed so that I have to have my package on github now or is there an alternative function I should use now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OpenCPU 2.0 was [released yesterday](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/opencpu/Ra9DeSVbXLM) and the single-user server has changed bit. To start an app and open it you now need to use `ocpu_start_app("user/repo")` for example:

```
ocpu_start_app("rwebapps/nabel")
```

Or to open a locally installed app:

```
devtools::install_github("rwebapps/nabel")
ocpu_start_app("nabel")
```

The manual page `?ocpu_start_server` has more examples and details.

Comment: Thanks. I had actually just worked that out too, so thanks for the quick reply. One more note is that I used to have to prepend "library" to the package name but this seems no longer necessary. So opencpu$browse("library/myapp/www") now becomes ocpu_start_app("myapp").